# What determines the Lifetime of $Z$-Boson?

Tags: standard-model, electroweak, half-life

What determines the lifetime of the Z Boson?  Is it it's mass? What else is involved? Is the coupling to Higgs involved?

Comment: Its decay modes, of course. Are you familiar with lifetime calculations in QFT? The masses of all of its decay products are also linked to the Higgs field. Why don't you write down a summary of its width from the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-z-boson.pdf)?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with the calculations and very unfamiliar....so dumb it down to basic simplicity please....and define the purpose of the decay widths in determining lifetimes, as well as couplings please.

Answer (score 1):

A $Z$ boson can decay to a variety of final states. About 70% of the time, it decays into a quark-antiquark pair, which proceed to create a jet of particles due to the strong interaction. About 20% of the time it decays into a neutrino-antineutrino pair. About 10% of the time it decays into a charged lepton-antilepton pair.

For each possible type of decay, one can use Feynman diagrams and Fermi’s Golden Rule to calculate the [decay rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate) for that channel, which is the probability per unit time that the particle will decay in that way. The rate will depend on the mass of the $Z$, the masses of the final decay products and any intermediate particles, and the relevant coupling constants, the conceptually relevant ones being how strongly the $Z$ couples to quarks, neutrinos, and charged leptons due to the weak interaction. (Jet production from the quark and antiquark would involve the strong coupling constant for QCD.)

You add together the decay rates for the various channels, and take the inverse of that to get the $Z$ lifetime.

Comment: Thank you G. Smith.....just what I was looking for. Excellent explanation. So if we want to explain the  short range of the Z Boson (in weak interaction), should we blame the high mass or the extremely short lifetime? or a combination.?

Comment: The short range of the weak interaction is normally attributed to the mass of the $W$ and $Z$ bosons, not to their lifetime. I’m tempted to claim that the range would be short even if the bosons couldn’t decay at all, but I think that is probably an impossible scenario.

Comment: Interesting... Since the Higgs scalar boson gives the formerly massless gauge Z boson its longitudinal spin to create mass, ?..then.if we prevented the Higgs longitudinal coupling (or break its coupling) wouldn't it prevent the decay of the gauge Boson  and extend its range?